# How to correctly set a persist flag when I execute "adb reboot" in AOSP?

Tags: android-source, android-8.0-oreo

According to the subject, I only found out the right .c file to set persist flag in "adb shell reboot"( system/core/reboot/reboot.c), but I can't find it in "adb reboot". What the difference between the two reboot commands??

Answer (score 1):

The flags governing the initial behavior of adbd are "ro" and therefore cannot be altered on a running system, but rather only by re-generating the boot image.

The relevant section of the source code for [should_drop_privileges()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/6b970212fd0b5ac9be05a5ddfd87e8350079fff6/adb/daemon/main.cpp#61) has an explanatory comment.

```
// The properties that affect `adb root` and `adb unroot` are ro.secure and
// ro.debuggable. In this context the names don't make the expected behavior
// particularly obvious.
//
// ro.debuggable:
//   Allowed to become root, but not necessarily the default. Set to 1 on
//   eng and userdebug builds.
//
// ro.secure:
//   Drop privileges by default. Set to 1 on userdebug and user builds.
```

Typically your goal would be accomplished by using an `eng` rather than `userdebug` build or else by customizing these settings to different values than the default for your chosen build flavor.

- `eng`

  - *defaults* to root
  - adbd runs by default
  - does not require adb keys
  - ro.debuggable=1, ro.secure=0
- `userdebug`

  - allows `adb-root`
  - adbd runs by default
  - does not require adb keys
  - ro.debuggable=1, ro.secure=1
- `user`

  - does not allow `adb-root`
  - adbd off by default until enabled in Settings
  - requires adb keys
  - ro.debuggable=0, ro.secure=1

Realistically it may be easiest to just execute the `adb root` each time you need to use it.  In a script you might follow it by a sleep of a second or two or better yet poll for the device to start responding again. Ultimately try to work the things you need to do as root into the original configuration of the built system such that you can end up with a `user` flavor build (`adb root` unsupported) in production, unless your goal is to make a device for experimentors rather than turnkey users.